# What do @$ and $$ mean in Perl?

Tags: perl, variables, syntax

OK, so two questions on odd syntax. I am working on some older Perl code that needs modification, and I came across the following line:

```
@$tmp=split(/,/,$tmpVals);
```

I have no idea how to read this, it looks like the RHS is splitting the variable string on ,      so that's fine, but it is the left hand side I am thrown by. What in the world is `@$`, as far as a I know it isn't a default variable. DOes anyone know its significance?

And then there is `$$`, which I have read normally represent the Perl PID. However, in this case it comes right before a veriable/assignment statement. Does it have a related effect there?

```
$$tmp=$row[1];
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What you're looking at are not special perl variables, but instances of references. They're described in [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html).

These are symbolic references: If `$tmp` contains "myvar", then the variable `@myvar` will be assigned to. The same applies to the second example.

Comment: Looks like you are right. Google tends to not return results when searching for those odd symbols. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Brian: If this solved your problem, click the check mark next to it to give Michael credit for the answer

Comment: Thanks, just confirmed it. Perl should require parenthesis for this feature, it's clear when the symbols are seperated, such as: $($varname)

Comment: There is no way to know from the provided code whether these are symbolic or "hard" references. The same syntax will work in either case (except that symbolic references are not allowed under `use strict`)

Comment: After looking at the accompanying code, I believe they are symbolic references. I hope to clean the code up enough to be able to run with 'use strict'. Thanks.

Comment: @Brian => you can use `@{$tmp}` which means the same thing as `@$tmp`.  Perl lets you drop the braces when the variable is a simple scalar.

Comment: @friedo true enough; I was just guessing based on the context that they were probably being used that way. I originally just included the reference, but added the explanation of symbolic refs since I guessed that was what applied.

Comment: The link 'perlref' (http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref) no longer exists. What was it?

Comment: In the command prompt or in terminal the following command `perldoc perlref` is the best link to understand the same.